# My details view is not updating?

Tags: asp.net, sql-update, detailsview

could you please tell me why nothing happens when I update my details view using the following code

```
 protected void newOrderDetailsView_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox txtNote = (TextBox)newOrderDetailsView.FindControl("txtNote");
        TextBox txtOrderDate = (TextBox)newOrderDetailsView.FindControl("txtOrderDate");
        TextBox txtDueDate = (TextBox)newOrderDetailsView.FindControl("txtDueDate");
        TextBox txtCustPO = (TextBox)newOrderDetailsView.FindControl("txtCustPO");
        TextBox txtContact = (TextBox)newOrderDetailsView.FindControl("txtContact");

        string Query = "Update Orders Set note='" + txtNote.Text + "' ,orderDate =CAST('" + txtDueDate + "'AS DATETIME) ,dueDate = CAST('" + txtDueDate + "'AS DATETIME) ,customerPurchaseOrder='" + txtCustPO.Text + "',contact='" + txtContact.Text + "' where orderId =" + ParentOrder;
        ExecuteQuery(Query);

        StatusLbl.Text = "Order Updated";
    }

        private void ExecuteQuery(string Query)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = DataAccess.Connection.GetDBConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

when I press the update button the message I actually put in the event handler is displaying but the no update is happening

EDIT: So I tried to enter the values directly and it worked and the Update was a success, ...What am I missing here??? HELP PLEASE

Comment: put a breakpoint in your code where you have `SqlConnection con = DataAccess.Connection.GetDBConnection();` - your code is going through the `try catch` dying and then coming back because you're not handling the error.

Comment: I got it...it turns out I was getting the values the wrong way, it should be like this:
cmd.Parameters.Add("@note", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = e.NewValues["note"].ToString();

Comment: well - that would have been impossible to point out as you haven't posted ANY use of parameters in your question.. good that you have fixed it though..